# ANN for object identification: how to prepare input data for learning (signals with varying length) and what structure to use?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am trying to artificial neural network as an instrument to identify some specific "peaks" in noised signals and get their coordinates.
I want to use keras for that purpose.

But I don't get how to prepare data for learning, can you suggest some example similar to my task or provide a link for the material?

Currently I have signals that are presented as csv files y_i(x_i) where i stand for the number of point (I am reading each file as a dataframe and converting it to numpy arrays for processing).

For each signal I have a file in csv format where I have x | y values in a row.
Let's say it's called `signal1.csv`

I have >500k of signals.

An example of a signal is presented on the next figure:

[image: Signal form form to consider]

The green lines visualize the actual peak positions (I have separate files for each signal which stand for actual peak positions for each corresponding signal - it's manually evaluated by experts). Let's say `signal1_solution.csv` - each peak has it's own set of parameters, and one of them is peak position.

I want to learn ANN to find peaks in raw signals.

**Supposed approach.** The signal will be given to the input of a ANN (two arrays, x & y - with similar number of points inside each, I can also provide additional parameters also for ANN: like average distance between peaks or some known params for that group of signals but I don't think it's necessary from the start).

Is it relatively  large number of inputs? (20000 floats) Maybe it's too much for that purpose and what can be done in this case?

After processing the signal by ANN it must return an array of calculated positions of peaks - and here I don't know the number of outputs, e.g. one signal will have 10 peaks - so the ANN must return 10 floats, and the other will have 110 peaks - so the ANN must return 110 floats. I can probably predict the maximum number of peaks in output just by calculating statistically (e.g. in the current data available for learning it is 170) and it really depends on the range of x of a signal - the wider the range - the larger number of peaks.

Each Signal consists of varying number of points, some can have 100 or 1000 points, 45% has more than 6000 points - up to 100000 points, the grid is nonuniform, so x[i]-x[i-1]<>x[i+1]-x[i].

At the same time each signal has varying number of peaks one signal has 50 peaks, another only 10 peaks - it depends on a distance between separate peaks expressed in x-coordinates.

There are complexed set of rules that are used by experts to estimate positions of peaks. One of them is the use of known statistical distributions of peaks parameters on the observable interval of X (e.g. distance between neighboring peaks). I suppose this information can be extracted during the learning process.

Maybe you can suggest how to prepare the data for learning in this case or label existing?

I had an idea just to label point by point (for each point of a signal I will mark if it belongs to the peak or not). But it's a problem because of the grid (the solution contain coordinate of a peak between some points of a signal and it can be on a relatively large distance to the nearest point in the signal).

**UPDATE 1:**
As I said - all signals are stored as separate csv-s in  folder.

An example of of one signal is shown in the first figure, here is the corresponding dataframe:

```
one_example_signal = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0)


             E  exp_trans   exp_trans_unc   marked_points
index               
4883    20.005036   0.710289    0.057905    0
4882    20.012073   0.780100    0.060669    0
4881    20.019113   0.808801    0.063798    0
4880    20.026157   0.676023    0.053775    0
4879    20.033205   1.006920    0.072483    0
```

The informative columns are: `E` - it's actually x-coordinate on the plot, `exp_trans` - it's an y coordinate on the plot and the `marked_points` - it's a predefined 'point class'. I need to explain the point class column for better understanding.
Full csv can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11sHeDj6DiKWgQ4cj56Ts4OPChPdAfYA-/view?usp=sharing

[image: Visualized example of one signal on the input of ANN]

[image: Region zoomed for better explanation of data specifics]

I have built a simple labeler that assigns a class to each point of the signal - e.g. points of clearly defined peaks have class 1, points nearest to the real peak left have class 2, points nearest from the right side has class 3.. Points that don't belong to the peak has class 0. They all are marked on the figure with various colors. Vertical lines help to understand where the real peaks are.

For the signal on the fig. statistics is as follows (we have 4884 pairs of points for that specific signal).

```
0    4779
2      38
3      37
1      30
```

So 4779 points are labeled as "not peaks", 38 points are labeled as "left boundaries", "right boundaries" - 37, and the closest to the real peaks - 30 points labeled (it's done using predefined model).

The idea was to feed ANN with the signal array: E - 4884 values corresponding to the E-coordinate and 4884 values of exp_trans (9768 points total).
The ANN outputs 4884 values that classifies each point of the input signal - it's a peak or not. If that makes sense :)

Comment: I think your problem name is "time series anomaly detection" you can find articles about it, the main idea is to split your data into window of a fixed input, labelise this window with the presence or not (and in your case the position) of the outliers and train the neural network on it. My first thought was to use a recurrent neural network but you can probably find other architecture that works too

Comment: Alexandre, thanks for your comment. And Merry Christmas if you celebrate :) I have marked all the points in the signal. E.g. I have 7000 points in the signal each of them is classified using 3 predefined classes - 0 - for the points that are not the resonance, 1 - for the nearest left point and 2 for the nearest right point. But I don't get how to pass that information to the keras.. Because each signal it's a separate dataframe in this case. Should I concatenate them in one? or how to prepare a learning dataset in this case?

Comment: Merry christmas ! 
Well, can you post an extract of the dataset ? It would really help me understand the problem (like a pandas head() call)

Comment: Alexandro, I have updated the question and added the dataset - structure, plot for better understanding and a link to the example signal I have. the problem is I have labelled data and understand what I should have on the input and output of ANN - but I don't get how to arrange it for learning process. E.g. should I prepare one large dataframe? or it's better to use some object to build a data structure for learning - e.g. one million signals each of them will have 5000 points inside.. and corresponding 5000 outputs for each signal. How should I normalize the training data then?